# Highcharts - Can it do this type of graph?

Tags: highcharts

Can Highcharts do a graph like this?  I know how to do the bar and the spline, I'm interested in the shaded "fastest mile" section at the start of the graph.

Thanks!

[image: example here --> (http://www.firehole.us/screen-capture.png)]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the api section on [plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands).

> xAxis.plotBands
>
> A colored band stretching across the plot area marking an interval on
>   the axis.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a try and post back.  Thanks!